# Excel VBA to query user info from LDAP returns "Provider does not support the property"

Tags: excel, vba, ldap, user-defined-functions, ado

## TLDR;

```
  Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
  cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=ADSDSOObject"
  cnn.Open
```

returns `Provider does not support the property` on line 3.

every variation of the above that I have tried returns the same.

## Whole story

In excel, I want to create a look-up table to return user information from LDAP based on the user ID.  The directory is very large, so loading the whole directory as a lookup table via Power Query is not feasible.  Something like this is what I'm trying to achieve:

| user ID | Full Name | Email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| myUid | *My name form LDAP* | *My Email from LDAP* |
| urUid | *Ur name form LDAP* | *Ur Email from LDAP* |

To achieve this, I am trying to create one or more UDFs (user defined function) in excel, which are powered by VBA.

In VBA it *seems* I need to use ADO (ActiveX Data Object) to connect to the [ADSDSOObject provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-microsoft-active-directory-service).

Following instructions there, as well as all over SO and the greater internet, I have tried to initiate this connection, but it always fails with the above error.

I took the code down to the most simple version from all the examples and was able to identify that the error occurs when running the `.open`.  Watching the `cnn` variable, I can see that this is the point when the `Errors` changes from empty to `1` and the details show the error message.

### Before line 2:

[image]

### After line 2:

[image]

I can see that the `ConnectionString` has been changed, but I can't identify *which* property is not supported by the provider...

The resultant connection string is `Provider=ADsDSOObject;Encrypt Password=False;Mode=Read;Bind Flags=0;ADSI Flag=-2147483648;`

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-microsoft-active-directory-service?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks @MaciejLos.  I've actually looked there and linked that article in the question.

Comment: OK. Have seen this: https://gist.github.com/mbirth/c9fb0d6c7ce118ad5eb4 ?